# app.get or router.get post, delete, patch etc., failing when sending an http request as a URL parameter or variable

Tags: node.js, reactjs, routes, react-router, fetch

I just wasted a lot of time trying to send an url in a fetch from a React app to a nodejs server. The server would not detect the request at all, even though the route was correct! I was very frustrated. Then I realized that if I sent anything else other than the url, the route actually worked and responded correctly, so why was the route becoming muddled by me including a url either as a parameter, as a variable or even if I included it inside an object property?

the raw string was an url address to an image:

```
const string = 'https:://zzz.io/yyyyy/products/image.jpg'

fetch(`https://xxxx.io/yyyyyy/products/{"isId":false,"identification":"${string}"}`, requestOptions)
```

the route wouldn't be hit at the server and a not found error would be reported.

I tried using:

```
const string = encodeURIComponent('https:://zzz.io/yyyyy/products/image.jpg')
```

, and curiously react would add the last url that had been used by the app to the string, messing the intended url completely.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lied in the root cause of the problem, I had to rediscover the powder... The forward slash was messing everything up and I probable discovered what for many of you was obvious to start with, you can have a / anywhere in the fetch call other than in the main url you are fetching. Once I understood this, then the solutions became obvious:

Solution 1: you can remove the slash and re-insert it in the server and everything would work.

Or

Best Solution:

simply replace the forward slash in your client API string with %2F and then call fetch and the nodejs server app and/route will be happy and work like a charm. Very simple to do and no need to use functions like encodeURIComponent, that in my case only added confusion. Just do:

```
string.replace(/\//g, "%2F")
```

and then fetch as in the question.

Comment: There is a built-in function [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for doing the %xx encoding as the `/` is not the only character that needs to be encoded.

Comment: Yes, when I use it inside reactapp API it added the last route that my app used to the route for no reason! Out of the blue!

Comment: The way you show using it in your question is incorrect.  You can't have things like `{"isId":false,"identification":"somestring"}` in your URL either.  Plus, it's very weird what you show here.  It appears you're trying to put JSON into the URL.  That is not typically what you would do.  Use query parameters if you want to put multiple property/value pairs into a URL, not JSON.

Comment: Thanks! Interesting! I am an E.E. and self taught myself full stack. I only program for myself and work alone. So no idea what is the correct way to do things. I could do this in many ways. Probably the best would be using the body. I was just testing what works and what doesn't. Found that JASON works perfect. No matter they type of request. So does using the body and the url with a mixture of params, queries and Jason. As long as you do not include a /. Didn't include this here but when I place the %2F instead of / it works on localhost but fails with a CORS error when using an external ip

Comment: First you decide if your request should be a GET or a POST or a PUT based on the type of request you're making (following the guidelines for REST requests).  If it's a GET, you only put data in a URL, not in the body.  If it's a POST or PUT, you typically put data in the body.

Comment: It was a DELETE request

Comment: For a DELETE request, the URL itself (with no body) should fully identify the resource you're trying to delete.  Most commonly, you would use URL path and/or query parameters to identify the resource.  You would not typically use JSON inside a URL.

Comment: Funny what you can do when you don't know you shouldn't and it works! Is this because the functionality is not guaranteed somewhere? I am at a loss for the why not, given that even nodejs provides a built in JSON.parse method.

Comment: In the end, you can put anything you want in a URL.  It just might have to be encoded because it contains characters that aren't allowed in URLs in that context.  But, there are norms and staying within those norms allows you to more easily work with lots of tools that are built to those norms.

Comment: For example, if you use query parameters like `?isID=false&identification=somestring`, then server environments will be able to automatically parse and use that.  If you encode JSON like `{"isId":false,"identification":"somestring"}` and put it in the URL, no server environment will automatically recognize that - you will have to write custom server code to recognize it and parse it.  That's because query parameters are self describing and the norm for how you pass URL parameters.

Comment: using the JSON.parse method in nodejs works like a charm for {..}. The only issue I found up to now is when I have to include an url as my property content. No matter how I handle it, even replacing the / with %2F it creates a weird problem for me, like not recognizing the route (even if the / is between quotes), or if I replace the / with $2F then it works on localhost but reports missing a CORS authorization even when it is there. I fixed it by modifying my server code and encoding the / myself both at the client and the server. Makes for extra funny security, and I accept it's not orthodox.